# Turning an array into a hash's keys, with a specified value for all items?

Tags: ruby, hash

Basically, I want to create the hash `{1959: 0, 1960: 0, 1961: 0, 1962: 0}` and so on without manually writing it out.

I figure I start with `[*1959..2014]` but don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You can't. That is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash::[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Hash[(1959..1962).map { |x| [x, 0] }]
# => {1959=>0, 1960=>0, 1961=>0, 1962=>0}
```

or [`Enumerable#to_h`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_h) in Ruby 2.1+:

```
(1959..1962).map { |x| [x, 0] }.to_h
# => {1959=>0, 1960=>0, 1961=>0, 1962=>0}
```

(changed the ending year for brevity of outputs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inject` with your array to form the hash, like so:

```
(1959..2014).inject({}) { |hash, year| hash[year] = 0; hash }
```

`inject` is like each in that in runs over each member of an enumerable, but it passes 2 arguments to the block, the current object and an object that you can use to collect the results, in this case a hash.

Or, as @sawa points out in the comment below:

```
(1959..2014).each_with_object({}) { |year, hash| hash[year] = 0 }
```

`each_with_object` doesn't require you to return the object at the end of the block like `inject` does.

[edit] Just used the plain range, rather than an array. Added `each_with_object` option.

Comment: You don't need to convert the range into an array. That is extra step and is waste. And `each_with_object` would work better here.

Comment: Thanks, added the `each_with_object` option. Didn't realise it would be more useful than `inject`.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
Hash[[*1959..2014].product([0])]
```

Comment: Or in Ruby 2.1, `[*1959..2014].product([0]).to_h`